# Using ODE to model a discrete phenomenon

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology

**SETTING**

In [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225653989_Sustainable_management_of_an_alpine_national_park_Handling_the_two-edged_effect_of_tourism) paper the authors study the effects of tourism in a national park in Austria on a endangered species of bird. They model the species size (number of breeding couples) with a continuous function of time $S = S(t)$ satisfying the following logistic ODE (with time dependent carrying capacity)
$$
\dot{S}(t) = \gamma S(t)\left(1 - \frac{S(t)}{\beta H(t)}\right), \qquad S(0) = S_0 > 0
$$
where $\gamma, \beta > 0$ are constants and $H = H(t)$, which represent the habitat extent, satisfies the following logistic ODE
$$
\dot{H} = \alpha H(t) \left( 1 - \frac{H(t)}{K} \right), \qquad H(0) = H_0 >0,
$$
with $K >0$ constant.

**QUESTION**: How reasonable is to model the dynamic of the size of a population with a continuous function $S$? For a very large population, I wouldn't see any problem, but in the specific case analyzed in the paper, $S_0 = 12$ and they argue in the appendix A.2 that the partridge carrying capacity is of 16 breeding couples. Therefore the actual discrete function that the authors want to model has a very limited range and I wonder, how legitimate it is to use an ODE.

A more realistic model would be to use a discrete state dynamic system to model the population dynamic (actually a stochastic process would probably be even more suitable) and I wonder how legitimate is to approximate such a system with an ODE.

Any suggestion/idea is very welcome! Even heuristic arguments.

**PS**: I am definitely more familiar with ODE than with discrete state systems.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I was thinking that maybe it can be justified from trial: if the model shows accurate enough results, then there is no need to justify anymore than that.

Comment: I haven't found any answer yet, but I must admit that I haven't been thinking too much about it anymore. I still believe that modelling the dynamics of such a small population seems a bit questionable. It would be nice to know whether using discrete state dynamic system yields different qualitative result than using an ODE.